# Cordova AdMob plugin 404 error: http://registry.cordova.io/com.admob.AdmobPlugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I´m getting the following error when trying to install admob plugins for Cordova:

```
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/com.admob.AdmobPlugin
npm http 404 http://registry.cordova.io/com.admob.AdmobPlugin
```

I have:

```
$ cordova --version
4.1.2
```

This is happening for several plugins:

```
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-ad-admob
npm http 404 http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-ad-admob
```

Please help -_-

Comment: You need to state what the issue is. We do not read minds.

Answer (score 0):

I found my cordova version was out of date.

The error is the 404 not found message trying to install any 3d party plugin.

Cheers,